# Issues with sending $_POST data to an outside server via cURL

Tags: php, jquery, forms, email, curl

The company I work for stores contacts into a 1shoppingcart database. We recently signed up for FreshAddress to validate emails before the information is sent to 1shoppingcart.

In order to get this information to 1shoppingcart I stored the name in a session - since it seemed that after the validation script ran that it cleared any form data aside from the email address it was validating, and the remaining hidden values that would normally be in the form as hidden input fields.

Everything transfers over except for the second ar variable. This is how it would normally look inside the form itself:

`<input name="ar" type="hidden" id="ar" value="000000">`
`<input name="ar" type="hidden" id="ar" value="000000">`
`<input name="ar" type="hidden" id="ar" value="000000">`

In order to send the information over I stored what normally would be hidden values in the form as php variables and placed them into an array to be sent over through. Again, the name, e-mail and everything else works except that $ar2 is not being stored for some reason. Here is the code I have:

```
    if($submitPage === true) {
    $name = $_SESSION['Name'];
    $email = $_POST['Email1'];
    $merchId = '000000';
    $arTY = 'Url to redirect goes here';
    $copyarresponse = '0';
    $custom = '0';
    $ar1 = '000000';
    $ar2 = '000000';
    $ar3 = '000000';
    $allwMulti = '0';
    $visiblefields = 'Name, Email1';
    $requiredFields = 'Name, Email';

    // where are we posting to?
    $url = 'http://www.mcssl.com/app/contactsave.asp';

    // what post fields?
    $fields = array(
       'merchantid' => $merchId,
       'ARThankyouURL' => $arTY,
       'copyarresponse' => $copyarresponse,
       'custom' => $custom,
       'ar' => $ar1, $ar2, $ar3,
       'allowmulti' => $allwMulti,
       'visiblefields' => $visiblefields,
       'requiredfields' => $requiredFields,
       'Name' => $name,
       'Email1' => $email
    );

    // build the urlencoded data
    $postvars = http_build_query($fields);

    // open connection
    $ch = curl_init();

    // set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postvars);

    // execute post
    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    // close connection
    curl_close($ch);
    session_destroy();

    }
```

The code basically runs when the e-mail that has been validated, returns as safe to send and $submitPage is set to true.

I have looked through this forum and various other sources online as well as contacted 1shoppingcart and fresh address and have had no luck as to what could possibly be preventing the second ar variable from being stored.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: `array('ar' => $ar1, $ar2, $ar3, )` is not valid PHP code.

Comment: Well, actually it is, but not the way you expect. What you most probably want would be `'ar' => array($ar1, $ar2, $ar3),`

Comment: Unfortunately it still seems like $ar2 is not being stored into the database. I'm not sure why it keeps skipping that variable.

Comment: Well, that's impossible to answer without the server side code behind the form that writes it into the database.

Comment: When I called 1shoppingcart, the publisher of the script that stores it into the database, they were unable to tell me any information on how the contact save script handles the data.
I appreciate your help though!